# phptal - using defined variables in php conditions

Tags: phptal, template-tal

I would like to use defined variables by phptal within php conditions as follows :

```
...
<tal:block define="className php: (photoIndex < 10) ? 'thumbItem thumbColumn1' : ( (photoIndex == 10) ? 'thumbItem thumbColumn2 thumbReset' : 'thumbItem thumbColumn2' )">
<tal:block define="defaultVal photo/isDefault">
<tal:block define="classNameWithIndex php: defaultVal ? '${className} modalMegaPhotoSelect' : '${className}'">
<li tal:attributes="class classNameWithIndex">
...
```

Here my output is "${className} modalMegaPhotoSelect" where as I expect it to be as "thumbItem thumbColumn1 modalMegaPhotoSelect" - the exact expectation is irrelevant the idea is the className should be percieved as a variable -

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `'${className}'` simply use `className`.

Instead of `'${className} modalMegaPhotoSelect'` use `className . ' modalMegaPhotoSelect'` (with spaces around `.`).